# Minimum comment length?

Tags: comments

I have yet to find a snippet or a solution to enforce a minimum comment length.

Most validation modules deal with fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom validator to form using `hook_form_alter` in your custom module.

```
function custom_mod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch($form_id){
    case 'comment_form':
      $form['#validate'] = array_merge( $form['#validate'], array('custom_validator'));
    break;
  }
}
```

Define the logic to restrict the length of comment length

```
function custom_validator($form, $form_state){
    if(strlen($form_state['values']['comment']) < 50)
       form_set_error('comment', t('No No....'));
}
```